# migration analytics management clientlogin

Tags: .net, api, google-analytics, migration

I was using Google Analytics API to show users of my CMS their visitor data. All profiles are under my own account, so using clientlogin and some Google .net libraries I was able to retrieve all web id's of the accounts to query data. Now since the API is deprecated all requests for account return a 404.

I have tried everything to update to 2.4 but without any success. What would be the way to go for me? Since I only need to login once with my own account instead of redirecting users to accept my app..

Using service accounts? I also have a server api key, but I have no idea how to implement the new API's. Too bad there is no .net library yet.
Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you are running into is they removed the Account Feed that was included in version 2.3 of the API. That means any sort of information about accounts, web properties, profiles, and goals all won't work using the old client libraries. The rest of it, aka the data queries, *should* still work and you should upgrade them as per the [migration documents](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdata-migration-guide).

To fix the issue you are having getting profiles you have to switch over to their [management api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v2/mgmtFeedReference). The easiest fix would be to gut out your old method of getting profiles and replace it with a simple restful implementation of their management api. The rest of your library (such as getting visitors/visits) should still work fine.

Heres a little example:

1) Use [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps) to get an auth token.

2) Grab the profiles xml by sending a GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles. Make sure to include the authorization header in the request `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("GoogleLogin auth={0}", clientLoginAuthToken));`

3) Use XDocument to parse the results!

Comment: I'm glad I can help! Hope it saved you a lot of the frustration I went through haha

Comment: Managed to get the table-ids with a getrequest and the clientlogin. Data API was still working as you said.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone needs to get their table ids from the new analytics api management feed using a webrequest and clientlogin. Here's my (quick) code(thanks to Bengel):

```
string queryString = String.Format("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email={0}&Passwd={1}&service=analytics&source={2}", __username, __pass, "yourlog");
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(queryString);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    string responseContent = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    string authCode = responseContent.Substring(responseContent.LastIndexOf("Auth=") + 5);

    queryString = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles";
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(queryString);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("GoogleLogin auth={0}", authCode));
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()));

    var entries = (from item in doc.Root.Elements("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry")
                   select new
                   {
                       tableid = item.Elements("{http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009}property").ElementAt(4).Attribute("value").Value,
                       profileid = item.Elements("{http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009}property").ElementAt(1).Attribute("value").Value
                  });
```

Comment: Have you happened to have upgraded to v3.0 for fetching profile info? This code works well for 2.4 of course but the output does not include 'WebsiteURL' - v3.0 does include it and I need that, wondering if you already upgraded before I tried to figure it out myself?

Comment: No sorry, other priorities :)